# apache server on ubuntu 14.04 restart fails

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

meraj@meraj-SATELLITE-C850-A785:~$ /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail]

what should i do to restart it .

Comment: What do the logs say?

Answer (score 2):

1. `$ sudo service apache2 restart`
2. Type your password